# Sqlite3 indexes after deleting an element

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite3 in my project and a have a problwm with elements indexes. There are 2 columns in my table "number"(index) and "user_input". For example, if we have 5 notes in this table their indexes are 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. If user who added note with index number 3 deletes his note, indexes bicome like 1,2,4,5. Is it possible to make them like 1,2,3,4 using any sql function?

Comment: What is the purpose of this index value? Identifying the notes?

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y Problem™. Gapless sequences are rarely used in the real world. Why do you think you need one?